# Página de error

Tags: php, javascript, html5, css3

tengo una pregunta, como puedo hacer para que un usuario no entre directamente  a una página de error, como una página 404 algo asi, pero que no  pueda entrar al escribir la direccion de esa pagina en la url?? Esque yo con javascript redirecciono a una página de error, pero no quiero que los usuarios entren directamente, como le puedo hacer??, Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Generalmente los servidores web manejan una página por defecto para los errores 400, como la 404 que mencionas. ¿Tú quieres tener tu propia página 404, sin mediar el servidor?

Comment: Asi es, dije 404 por decir nomas un ejemplo, no quiero la 404, yo hice una pagina que dice cierto error, y quiero saber como hacer para que los usuarios no entren directamente, a esa pagina de error.

Comment: Uhm, si vas a usar php para ello, podrías crearla mediante un `include`: que sea tu mismo index.php el que maneje el asunto, y muestre el archivo "mi_error.php" mediante `include`: a ese archivo en el servidor (mi_error.php) le asignas permisos para que no se pueda abrir desde el navegador (creo que se puede hacer eso...) o mejor aun, simplemente le pones dentro un `if` que verifique que estás abriendo el archivo en modo `include` y no directamente desde el navegador.

Comment: A mi se me ocurre que con PHP mires el referer y con ello sabes si es una entrada directa o desde una URL con error aunque te advierto que si el usuario es avispado, puede falsear el referer y podría acceder igualmente.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo: "Tengo que hacer esto y no se por donde empezar" no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre muy amplia y no encaja en el formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Lo logre con javascript, muchas gracias x sus respuestas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con el archivo htacces en tu server puedes colocar lo siguiente dentro del archivo .

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^404/?$ 404.php
ejemplo 1:ErrorDocument 404               www.google.com.ve 
ejemplo 2:ErrorDocument 404               404.php
```

Si la primera linea esta colocada "rewriteEngine On" Dejala como esta y pega en el archivo las siguientes.

La ultima linea es un ejemplo puedes colocar o la ruta de tu web o la ruta a un archivo tenga en su interior la informacion de redireccionamiento

copialo y pegalo sin "ejemplo 2:"

cuando tengas ya hecho esto , lo siguiente seria que prepararas el archivo 404.php con una bonita libreria llamada sweet alert

```
<html>
<head>
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert2@7.15.1/dist/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>


swal({
  title: 'Pagina web no encontrada',
  text: 'Redireccionando al inicio',
  imageUrl: '404-2.png',
  imageWidth: 400,
  imageHeight: 200,
  timer: 9999,
  allowOutsideClick: false,
  onOpen: () => {
    swal.showLoading()
  }
}).then((result) => {
  if (
    // Read more about handling dismissals
    result.dismiss === swal.DismissReason.timer
    ) {
    console.log('I was closed by the timer')
    window.location.href = "tu pagina web o archivo en tu servidor"; 
  }
})

</script>

</body>

<!--   allowOutsideClick: false,-->

   </html>
```

con eso redirigiras a cualquiera que coloque una url mala de tu pagina y lo mandaras a google o la pagina que tu quieras con un mensaje de espera.

Esto te va a servir para no perder visitas en tu web chato . 
Si te sirve me dices , si no , puedo ayudarte un poco mas para que lo logres

aqui te puedo mostrar lo que hago , y seguramente lo que quieres hacer tu

http://www.grupodiarca.com/intranet/404.php

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, lo hice con javascript :)